# How can I use a class component at different places with unique IDs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, class

I want to use Buttons component in different places, but not as a continuous list of items.I can't use array.map method because it produces continuous list of components.I want to get list of (value)s from each Buttons component. I want to keep an 'id' for each of these (value)s, so that I can identify them

```
class Buttons extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      value: 0,

    };
    this.increase = this.increase.bind(this);
    this.decrease = this.decrease.bind(this);
  }

  increase(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.value < 10) {
       return this.setState(() => ({ value: this.state.value + 1 }));

    } else return null;
  }
  decrease(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    if (this.state.value !== 0) {
      return this.setState(() => ({ value: this.state.value - 1 }));
    } else return null;
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.decrease}>-</button>
        <label>{this.state.value}</label>
        <button onClick={this.increase}>+</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

I want to use the component as below

```
  <li>
       Adults <Buttons id={10} key={10} />
  </li>
  <li>
       Students <Buttons id={20} key={20} />
  </li>
```

Answer (score 0):

You probably want something like:

```
function MyComponent() {
  const [adults, setAdults]  = React.useState(0)
  const [students, setStudents]  = React.useState(0)

  render (
    <ul>
      <li>
        Adults <Buttons value={adults} onChange={setAdults} />
      </li>
      <li>
        Students <Buttons value={students} onChange={setStudents} />
      </li>
    </ul>
  )
}

function Button({ value, onChange }) {
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => onChange(value - 1)}>-</button>
      <label>{value}</label>
      <button onClick={() => onChange(value + 1)}>+</button>
    </div>
  )
}
```